# .NET Core pack with unmanaged dlls

Tags: .net-core, nuget

I have the following problem: I have a .NET library that depends on a set of unmanaged DLLs (by the way of `DllImport`).

I am trying, using .NET core command line tool, to create a `.NuPkg` package that includes the unmanaged DLLs in such a way that a project referencing this package can run and load the unmanaged DLLs.

What is the correct way of doing this? Specifically, what should the `.csproj` look like and are any other files required?

Comment: Do you realize that unmanaged dll may be runtime dependent?